# How to destory all users but current user(admin) in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this setup where it destroys all users but i want it not to destroy current user which is admin.

controller.

```
def remove_all

  User.destroy_all 
  redirect_to(admin_users_path, { flash: { success: 'You have wiped all the data on the website!' } })
end
```

navigation.html

```
<%= link_to "Nuke Button", remove_all_profiles_path, :method => :get %>
```

route:

```
resources :profiles do
    member do
      get :delete
    end
    collection do
      get 'remove_all'
    end
  end
```

I know I have to add something to the controller just don't know what to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have access to the current_user in your controller (or if not that, you know the id of the current user somehow

```
User.where.not(id: current_user.id).destroy_all
```

Note: In Rails 7 you will also be able to do

```
 User.excluding(current_user).destroy_all
```

Which is a bit nicer maybe, but this doesn't work yet.

https://blog.saeloun.com/2021/03/08/rails-6-1-adds-excluding-to-active-record-relation.html